# Apache Ignoring Custom Module

Tags: apache, apache-modules

So I am working on trying to make my own apache module.  Right now I trying to get it to return a 403 just to test it out, but it seems that apache just ignores the module entirely and returns the default page.   Here is the relevant parts of my code:

```
static int request_hook(request_rec* r){
  return HTTP_FORBIDDEN;
}

/* ********************************************
    Register module to Apache
   ******************************************** */

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *p)
{
    // We want to hook first so we can issue a deny ASAP if needed
    ap_hook_log_transaction( request_hook, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_REALLY_FIRST);
}

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA my_module = {
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    NULL,              /* dir config creater */
    NULL,                       /* dir merger --- default is to override */
    NULL,                       /* server config */
    NULL,                       /* merge server configs */
    NULL,                   /* command apr_table_t */
    register_hooks              /* register hooks */
};
```

And my apache configuration file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        SetHandler      my_module
</VirtualHost>
```

It was compiled by doing

```
sudo apxs -i -a -c my_module.c && sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: You need to tell Apache to load the module at the Apache instance level and not website level. Depending on your install of Apache you may have a loadmodules.conf file with all of the modules Apache should load. Otherwise you can just add to your HTTPD.conf "LoadModule module_name /path/on/your/disk/to/moduel.so"

Comment: I have the my_module.load file in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled and if I load the module manually in the vhost configuration I see in the logs "my_module already loaded".

Comment: What's your module supposed to do on a 403 forbidden exactly? The 403 forbidden stuff is part of the Apache core and all you can do if I am not mistaken is customize your 403 error page as a result.

Comment: My goal is to get apache to return a 403 forbidden response as opposed to an HTTP 200 response whenever the module is enabled.

Comment: So you are effectively trying to create your own maintenance module? If so this page is probably a good guide on how to do it without writing a module https://www.shellhacks.com/redirect-site-maintenance-page-apache-htaccess/

Comment: No.  I plan on adding more detailed authorization logic, but for the mean time I want it to just deny everyone as a sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.  The problem was the function:

```
ap_hook_log_transaction( request_hook, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_REALLY_FIRST);
```

should have been:

```
ap_hook_handler( request_hook, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_REALLY_FIRST);
```